# Tabs-like menu with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, tabs

I am trying to toggle the visibility of the elements like "id=tabs1, id=tabs2" when clicking the "li" elements. You will find that I succeeded in the not so arduous task of naming the IDs, but every attempt of making it work ended up in frustration

```js
$(function() {
  $(".din_nav li").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
/*DEATH IS NEAR! profile by DEVIANT*/

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div,
p,
span,
h1,
h2,
h3,
img {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
a {
  cursor: url(/cursor.gif), pointer;
}

::-moz-selection {
  color: white;
  background: #ff5aba6b;
}

 ::selection {
  color: white;
  background: #ff5aba6b;
}

body {
  background: #282828;
  position: relative;
  padding: 30px;
}

.credits {
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 1px solid white;
  font-family: 'Syncopate';
  font-size: 30px;
  letter-spacing: 100px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: -15px;
  transition-property: letter-spacing, width, border-radius;
  transition-delay: 0s, 0s, 0.5s;
  transition-duration: 0.5s, 0.5s, 0.5s;
  z-index: 666
}

.credits p {
  margin: 10px
}

.credits:hover {
  border-radius: 0%;
  width: 200px;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  font-size: 30px;
  transition-property: letter-spacing, width, border-radius;
  transition-delay: 0.5s, 0.5s, 0s;
  transition-duration: 0.5s, 0.5s, 0.5s;
}

#deathisnear {
  width: 560px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  font-smooth: always;
  color: white;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.din_header {
  height: 295px;
  background: black;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

.din_button p {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 8px 15px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.din_button p:hover {
  color: #ff65c0;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.din_nav {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 170px;
  background: black;
  margin: 40px;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: 'Consolas';
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #ff65c0;
  transition: 0.5s;
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
  /* visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0; */
  left: -50px;
}

.din_button:hover>.din_nav {
  left: 0px;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.din_nav h1 {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  text-transform: lowercase;
  color: white;
}

.din_nav li {
  list-style: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.din_nav li a {
  color: #ff65c0;
  text-decoration: none
}

.din_nav li::before {
  content: ">>>";
  margin-left: 22px
}

.din_nav li:hover,
.din_nav li a:hover {
  color: white!important;
}

.din_nav li:hover::after {
  content: "<3";
}

.din_header_title {
  font-family: 'Syncopate';
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 20px 0 15px
}

.din_header_img {
  height: 180px;
  background-image: url(/misamisa.png)
}

.din_header_sub {
  font-family: 'Nueva STD Condensed';
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 12px
}

.din_body {
  background: url(/paisaje2.png);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.din_p1bg {
  background: black;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  width: 80%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.din_p1top {
  font-family: 'Nueva STD Condensed';
  text-transform: lowercase;
  line-height: 25px;
}

.din_p1top h1 {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: oblique;
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-top: -18px
}

.din_p1top h2 {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

.din_p1top h3 {
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-top: -6px;
}

.din_heart {
  width: 280px;
  height: 103px;
  background: url(/heart.png)
}

.din_p1txt {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 30px 20px 20px 20px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  font-family: 'Consolas';
  color: #ff65c0;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 15px 5px;
  text-transform: lowercase;
}

.din_p1txt b {
  color: white;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.din_p1title {
  font-family: 'Syncopate';
  font-size: 32px;
  color: black;
  text-shadow: 1px 0 white, -1px 0 white, 0 1px white, 0 -1px white;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -125px;
  margin-top: -31px
}

.din_dis {
  width: 558px;
  height: 416px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1
}

.din_p2bg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 416px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.active,
.active a {
  color: white !important;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="deathisnear.css">
<script src="deathisnear.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#tabs").tabs();
</script>

<div id="tabs">
  <div id="deathisnear">
    <div class="credits">
      <p>
        Deviant
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="din_header">
      <div class="din_button">
        <p>
          死
        </p>
        <div class="din_nav">
          <h1>
            Pop up! >///
            < </h1>
              <ul>
                <li class="active">
                  <a href="#tabs1">Bitácora</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#tabs2">Retrato</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#tabs3">Galería</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#tabs4">Registro</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="din_header_title">Erika Grimes</div>
      <div class="din_header_img"></div>
      <div class="din_header_sub">I care not, a man can die but once; we owe God and death.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="din_body">
      <div class="din_p2bg" id="tabs2">
        hola
      </div>
      <div class="din_p1bg" id="tabs1">
        <div class="din_p1top">
          <div class="din_heart"></div>
          <h1>Deviant</h1>
          <h2>My Hero Academia</h2>
          <h3>07.05.23</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="din_p1title">Bitácora</div>
        <div class="din_p1txt">
          <p>
            <b>Raza</b> Humana<br>
            <b>Genero</b> Femenino<br>
            <b>Edad_aparente</b> Adolescente<br>
            <b>Agrupación</b> !undefined<br>
            <b>Quirk</b> !undefined<br>
            <b>Perfiles</b> !undefined<br>
            <b>Grupo_sanguíneo</b> !undefined<br>
            <b>Rango</b> D<br>
            <b>Alineamiento</b> Neutral<br>
            <b>Experiencia</b> 0/0/0<br>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So I made you a snippet. It immediately shows that you are trying to run `("#tabs").tabs();` BEFORE the HTML is rendered.. Also what is `deathisnear`, please include